# Multiline search and replace with quickfix list and :cdo

Tags: search, replace, ripgrep

I'm working on applying `doctrine/coding-standard` on `doctrine/orm`, and I would like to work smarter.

I would like to search occurences of

```php
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
```

and replace them with

```php
    /**
     * @var int
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
```

My current `grepprg` is `rg\ --vimgrep\ --smart-case`, so I tried `:gr '/\*\*\n     \* @Id\n     \* @Column.*"integer"\)\n     \* @GeneratedValue.*\n     \*/' --multiline tests/` (I'm planning to use `:cdo …` after that, which should be easy enough.

It finds the occurences alright, but it formats them in such a way that each line of the matched block is considered a separate occurence, like this:

```
tests/Doctrine/Tests/ORM/Functional/Ticket/DDC881Test.php:109:5:    /**
tests/Doctrine/Tests/ORM/Functional/Ticket/DDC881Test.php:110:5:     * @Id
tests/Doctrine/Tests/ORM/Functional/Ticket/DDC881Test.php:111:5:     * @Column(type="integer")
tests/Doctrine/Tests/ORM/Functional/Ticket/DDC881Test.php:112:5:     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
tests/Doctrine/Tests/ORM/Functional/Ticket/DDC881Test.php:113:5:     */
tests/Doctrine/Tests/ORM/Functional/Ticket/DDC881Test.php:189:5:    /**
tests/Doctrine/Tests/ORM/Functional/Ticket/DDC881Test.php:190:5:     * @Id
tests/Doctrine/Tests/ORM/Functional/Ticket/DDC881Test.php:191:5:     * @Column(type="integer")
tests/Doctrine/Tests/ORM/Functional/Ticket/DDC881Test.php:192:5:     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
tests/Doctrine/Tests/ORM/Functional/Ticket/DDC881Test.php:193:5:     */
```

That will not work well with `:cdo` I'm afraid.
Maybe it would work if `rg '/\*\*\n     \* @Id\n     \* @Column.*"integer"\)\n     \* @GeneratedValue.*\n     \*/' --multiline tests/ --vimgrep` printed the following instead:

```
tests/Doctrine/Tests/ORM/Functional/Ticket/DDC881Test.php:109:5:    /**
                                                                     * @Id
                                                                     * @Column(type="integer")
                                                                     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
                                                                     */
tests/Doctrine/Tests/ORM/Functional/Ticket/DDC881Test.php:189:5:    /**
                                                                     * @Id
                                                                     * @Column(type="integer")
                                                                     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
                                                                     */
```

How would you do such a complicated search and replace?

Comment: Probably I would grep something smaller and cdo a function call that checks for the whole pattern.

Comment: Ah so for some reason it would work with grep? Interesting, let me try!

Comment:  It does not seem that `grep` is able to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686147/how-to-find-patterns-across-multiple-lines-using-grep

Comment: No, I would `:grep` a single-line patter, and then do `:cdo call F()` where `F` examines the next few lines for a match and then applies the transformation. The `-r` trick is nice though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:
It's a bit hackish, but you can hijack `ripgrep`'s `--replace` flag, you can essentially replace each match with a single line one, producing the desired effect. In the end, what I did is the following:

```
:gr '/\*\*\n     \* @Id\n     \* @Column.*"integer"\)\n     \* @GeneratedValue.*\n     \*/' --multiline tests/ -r 'whatever, it does not matter'
:cdo call append('.', '     * @var int') | update
```

In more generic terms, _if `ripgrep` is your `grepprg`:

```
:gr 'some multiline pattern' --multiline tests/ -r 'whatever, it does not matter'
:cdo the colon command you want to execute for each occurence | update
```

The same does not seem to be doable with `grep`.